# Magento sales order view filter collection

Tags: magento, collections, filter, magento-1.7

I have a small problem.
I want to filter `admin sales order view` collection .
I tried , but failed to find the collection file .
please help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<sales_order_item_collection_load_before>
    <observers>
        <set_discount_new_customer>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>modulename_customattribute/observer</class>
            <method>filterCollection</method>
        </set_discount_new_customer>
    </observers>
</sales_order_item_collection_load_before>
```

In Observer file :

```
public function filterCollection($observer)
{
   $rawnew = $observer->getOrderItemCollection();
   $rawnew->addFieldToFilter('mycustom_attribute',6);
   return $rawnew;
}
```

*Thanks to R.S for giving hint .*

Answer (score 1):

Try these, Its working for me,

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app();
//echo $name = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();

$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('status', 'pending')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('customer_email', 'mail@domain.com')
    ;
foreach ($orders as $order) {
    $email = $order->getCustomerEmail();
    echo $email . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this using observer

in config.xml

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
    <sales_order_grid_collection_load_before>
        <observers>
            <magepal>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>magepal/observer</class>
                <method>handleOrderCollectionLoadBefore</method>
            </magepal>
        </observers>
    </sales_order_grid_collection_load_before>
```

In your observer

```
public function handleOrderCollectionLoadBefore($observer) 
{
     $collection = $observer->getOrderGridCollection();
     // $collection->addFieldToFilter('status', 'pending');
     // you may need to do additional check to make sure that the filter is only apply to specific section
```

Comment: R.S Thanks for the hint . If I want to use observer to calculate the grandtotal below which comes in yellow ... can it be done ?